# FormData: assign object without JSON.stringify

Tags: javascript, json

I want send to server data in this format:

```
{"post"=>{"body"=>"hello", "title"=>"321", "username"=>"1"}
```

But If I use FormData in this way:

```
var data = new FormData();
undefined
var a = {username: "1", title: "1", body: "1"}
undefined
data.append( 'post', a );
undefined
data.get("post")
"[object Object]"
```

I will get this:

```
{"post"=>"[object Object]"}
```

How I can to send data in right format?

Answer (score 0):

You are appending "a", but "a" is an object, specifically, a JSON object, which is why you see the `{"post"=>"[object Object]"}`.  Use `JSON.parse(a)` first to build your string.  See [JSON parse](http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_eval.asp)

Comment: `a
Object {username: "1", title: "1", body: "1"}`
`JSON.parse(a)
VM27411:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1(…)`

Comment: Are you able to put " " around username, title, and body and not the values in the key : value pairs?